# Как сделать multi-select folders в WPF?

Tags: c#

Как по мне достаточно тривиальный вопрос, но почему то как то все очень сложно и ним. Мне нужно сделать такое: юзер кликает на кнопку - открывается диалоговое окно - он там выбирает несколько папок - нажимает ок

Я не вижу ни одного толкового примера как это сделать (странно, что этого нет из коробки)

Нашел вот такое

http://www.ssware.com/articles/folderbrowserdialog-unmasked-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-the-folder-browser-component-from-dotnet-framework.htm

Там на втором скрине вроде как что то похожеее, но нет примера имплементации...

потом нашел еще вот такое

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/805b250b-ed99-4650-8b48-d3e3fde78204/multi-select-folder-in-wpf?forum=wpf

но опять же, нет нормального примера имплементации

Вопрос, как сделать выбор нескольких папок в C# WPF?

Comment: По первой ссылке так и пишут: `The folder browser component does not allow multiple folders to be selected.`

Comment: @Bulson да, согласен. Но второй скрин как мне показалось делает именно это...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению многое Microsoft не добавили в WPF, что приходится нам с вами компенсировать сторонними библиотеками и диалоги тут не исключение.

- Идем в NuGet и ставим пакет [WindowsAPICodePack-Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell) со всеми зависимостями.
- Дальше создаем сам объект диалога:

  ```
  using var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog
  {
      IsFolderPicker = true,
      Multiselect = true
  };
  ```

  Тут я использовал две настройки:

  1. `IsFolderPicker` - будет выбор среди директорий, а не файлов.
  2. `Multiselect` - необходимый вам `multi-select`.
- Ну и осталось нам вызвать окно и получить результат:

  ```
  if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
  {
      var folders = dialog.FileNames;
      MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", folders));
  }
  ```

Библиотечка имеет множество настроек, там уж думаю интуитивно разберетесь что да как.

Результат:

[image: Result]

Comment: Я новичек в C# можете обьяснить где добавляется это "Идем в NuGet и ставим пакет..."  это вот так можно сделать https://stackoverflow.com/a/24420985/5709159?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Все зависит от того, где вы пишете (какая IDE). В Visual Studio жмете правой кнопкой мыши по проекту - "Управление пакетами NuGet" - В поиске пишете "WindowsAPICodePack-Shell" и устанавливаете нужный. По ссылке выше установка идет через "Консоль диспетчера пакетов" ("Вид" - "Другие окна" - "Консоль диспетчера пакетов"), вам нужен `-Shell`.