# Как создать диалог выбора папки в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно, чтобы пользователь, нажимая на кнопку, мог выбрать папку (не файл) и потом путь до этой папки сохранялся в string переменной. Ничего осмысленного для WPF найти по этому поводу не сумел. Буду крайне признателен за помощь.

Comment: [Некоторые делают вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4547393/12888024). [Вот еще варианты](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17712949/12888024). Гугл - сила.

Comment: [Дубликат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1071699/220553)