# Как посмотреть папку через c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Для открытия файла я использую:

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Файлы рисунков (*.bmp, *.jpg, *.png)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            file = openFileDialog.FileName;
```

Каким образом я могу открыть FileDialog для директории? openFileDialog.Filter = "Папка (*Directory)|*directory";

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1071714/220553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть много различных Dialog`гов, например System.Windows.Forms.**FolderBrowserDialog** 
Используйте:

```
using(var folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
   if(folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderBrowser.SelectedPath))
         string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowser.SelectedPath);
}
```

Comment: А какую ссылку using нужно подключить?Без нее компилятор ругается

Comment: @ВалентинЗ., System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog

Comment: А вам не кажется странным, использование WinForms компонентов в WPF? Ужасный совет...

Comment: Единственный вариант, который я знаю. Не нашёл свой прошлый ответ, где я делал через Filter(Вроде бы нужно просто `*` втсавить, а не `Directory*`) делал

Comment: Не смешивайте два, совершенно разных вида проектов, это совершенно неверный подход! Да, в WPF не добавили эти диалоги, но их можно спокойно вызвать через WinAPI, либо использовать уже готовые компоненты, которые реализуют это все за вас. Под вопросом дал ссылку на ответ.